# How would I pragmatically write google analytics code into index.html header tag?

Tags: angular, google-analytics

Let's suppose I get all google analytics code from BE, what would be the best way to write it into index.html file? That's all I need, basic GA.

Comment: use Renderer2 to add a script content

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: any)
{
}

renderAnalyticsCode(codeToRender: string)
{
    const s = this.renderer.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.text = `
    /** add whetever javascript code here **/
    ${codeToRender}
    `;
    this.renderer.appendChild(this._document.head, s);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I won't be able to see if it works for a while though.

Comment: Do you mean because you have to wait for google analytics to collect stats?

Comment: Nah, I'll have to wait for my project to start... This was just one of requirements I got in advance, so I was curious how would I solve it.